# Why does my module with jit functions take so long to import?

Tags: python, numba

I have created a python module that I import into a jupyter notebook for general usage. I have a number of jit functions in the module, circa 20. The module can take up to a minute to import, but if I comment out the @njit decorators, the module will import instantaneously. I was wondering if any python wizzes know what's going on here under the hood at import. Is there any way I can bring down this agonizingly long import time?

Comment: The reason to use `jit` or `njit` is because it compiles the function to machine code so that it will run faster _on subsequent runs_ but remember that the first time there is overhead with that compile action. It seems like maybe you are waiting on that compile time on each function when it's imported

Comment: Thanks for this! Yeah that makes sense and I did consider that, but I thought it the code was compiled when the respective function was executed, i.e. when the code is ran, not at import?

Comment: Normally that's how it's supposed to work, but it may depend on how you implemented it. If you show some code from the script you're importing, and how you're importing it, that might help illuminate the issue

Comment: I think this is actually being caused by the fact that all my functions have signatures, therefore they are compiled to binaries at import. If I remove the signatures, the import is effectively instantaneous, however the first iteration of my simulation (the whole system is a Monte Carlo simulation) takes much longer, owing to the compile time.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to sort out the root cause. That's the downside to using numba in general, the compile time. It's really only a time saver if you're compiling the functions once and then using the same functions over and over

Comment: Yeah, ultimately I am using them over and over so I am seeing a big speedup. I just didn't realise the code was compiling at import before. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It might help other people to see this question in the future, so consider writing up your findings regarding signatures in an answer and accepting it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out that removing the signatures of my functions sped up the import time significantly. However, the first executions of the functions were significantly slower. If the functions have signatures, then the functions are compiled *at import*, this is due to the input and return types being known. If there are no signatures, then the functions are compiled *at execution*, as it is only at this point where the compiler knows the input and return types.